# lpWindowsName , how to find?

Tags: c#

I found this code on the Internet, but idk why it works only for Firefox.

It seems like the prorgam takes this string

```
 IntPtr WindowToFind = FindWindow(null, "Google - Mozilla Firefox");
```

from Windows bar. I tried to open tabs with different names and it also worked. But when I replace string Mozilla to Opera, it does not work at all.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104;
            const int VK_F5 = 0x74;

            IntPtr WindowToFind = FindWindow(null, "Google - Mozilla Firefox");

            PostMessage(WindowToFind, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, VK_F5, 0);


            Cursor.Position = new Point(500,500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-finder-tool?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa): FindWindow accepts the window title as a second parameter.

This code looks for a window with a title "Google - Mozilla Firefox" and sends F5 sys key button.
Opera's window title is probably named differently, so that's the reason it does not work.
You can use [SPY++ tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2019) to find the window title of Opera browser.

Generally, finding windows based on a title is not reliable as the title may change. The preferred way would be finding by `className` (first parameter of `FindWindow` function). You can also use SPY++ to find the class name of Opera.